# Loading file with namespace doesn't work?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

Take I have a completely separate (as in, somewhere in the file system) file:

```
(ns separate)

(def a "test")
```

Now, if I try to load that file like this:

```
(load-file "separate.clj")
(require 'separate)
(separate/a)
```

It throws an error saying that `separate` isn't found as a namespace. Why is this and how do I fix it?

EDIT: This is literally the code I'm running:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I need to do something like this:

```
(deref (get (ns-interns 'separate) 'a))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(require 'separate)
```

Should be:

```
(require '[separate])
```

There is no example in [clojuredocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require) probably because single part namespaces are unusual.

Comment: Doesn't work :( It tells me that the file couldn't be found. I've updated my question with an image of the code I'm executing.

Comment: Works on my repl. Have you checked the path you're passing to `load-file` is correct? I have used an absolute path `(load-file "/home/muhuk/tmp/separate.clj"`

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `str` to concat `*cwd*` with the path.

Comment: I might try to reinstall lein completely. The repl doesn't work for some reason as well.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Works in the REPL (even without requiring), but not when executed via `lein run`.